# How To Get FLV file URL from a webpage

Tags: php, flv, jwplayer

How To Get FLV file URL from a webpage LIKE ; http://panet.co.il/Ext/vplayer_lib.php?media=95865

Tanks

Comment: Way too vague. What does this have to do with the JW Player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to output it as video Try this on vplayer_lib.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: video/flv");
echo file_get_contents($pathToFLV);
?>
```